# From what height a cat can fall safely?

Tags: cats

There is a belief prevalent that cats can land on their paws harmlessly irrespective of the height. Assuming that the land below is plain soil, what can maximum if cat is drooped, it lands safely?

Comment: This sounds more like a question for [physics.se](http://physics.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @MattS. why physics and not pets?

Comment: @JamesJenkins "At what height can I drop X before it breaks?" It just happens to be that X=Cat.

Comment: The answer would also be dependant on the size and weight of the animal.

Comment: It would also be dependent on the age of the cat, which for me brings it back from Physics to Pets, but that is just me.

Comment: @MattS. - More biology actually, physics is better prepared to talk about falling objects that don't react to the fall.

Comment: Related: http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/4398/should-i-worry-about-my-cat-jumping-out-the-window

Comment: @Zaralynda your related looks like it makes this question a duplicate.

Answer (score 3):

There's a great term called "[feline high-rise syndrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-rise_syndrome)".

Roughly speaking, 90% of cats survive falls from 2-32 stories (approx 5-160 meters).

[A Straight Dope article from 1996](http://www.straightdope.com/columns/read/1143/do-cats-always-land-unharmed-on-their-feet-no-matter-how-far-they-fall) conjectured that higher falls give the cat time to rotate (feet-down) and then relax, which causes their excess of skin to act somewhat like a parachute. Specifically, the article says that falls over seven stories are more survivable.

[The 2004 Vnuk article specifically disputes this](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1098612X03001219), stating:

> Falls from the seventh or higher stories, are associated with more severe injuries and with a higher incidence of thoracic trauma.

The article also indicates a 96.5% survival rate, though half of those sustained limb fractures.

Incidentally, a [physics.stackoverflow article says a "righted and relaxed" cat has a terminal velocity around 100kph](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/109467/small-animal-terminal-velocity), while [reddit estimates a human's TV is about 160kph at the slowest (flat, stretched out)](http://www.reddit.com/r/askscience/comments/1193gy/if_the_terminal_velocity_for_humans_is_around_125/).

Comment: Point of clarification: the 90% figure in the second sentence is **not** of cats falling from 2-32 stories, but rather the percent of **survivors** who are taken in for treatment. In other words, if the cat isn't killed outright, **and** taken in to a veterinarian for treatment, there's a 90% chance they'll survive.  As is, I feel this answer understates the danger and risk to a cat from falling from great heights.

Comment: Yes, that stat is a good example of "selection bias"...the set of cats falling from high rises that reach the vet is not a random sample.

Comment: very true, Oldcat and Beofett. It's basically "ignoring cats that ran away, died, or were abandoned, most survive".