# Have there been cases of cat owners in high rise apartments being legally required to install screen (safety nets) on windows?

Tags: cats, safety, death, injury, legal

Sure, [cat owners should worry about their cats jumping out the window](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/4398/should-i-worry-about-my-cat-jumping-out-the-window).  I'm concerned with negligent/irresponsible cat owners.  For example, what if I see my neighbor's cat everyday on an open window of a high rising building, and I warn the owner about the risks, and one day the cat falls.  So my question is: Are you aware of cases in which owners were held legally responsible in those situations? Or do you know of a SPCA chapter lobbying for passing local laws requiring cat owners living in apartments above, say, fourth floor to install screen (safety nets) on windows? I know of apartments where different tenants have had multiple cats injured and die over the years. Unfortunately it seems acceptable for well-meaning though inexperienced cat owners to dismiss such real risks.

Comment: Good edit! I reopened it.